# ruby on rails observe_form help, how to exclude form field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a search form with text field and some checkboxes.  I need to exclude text field from observe_form .

= observe_form 'material_search_form', :url => list_filter_search_url, :frequency => 1, :update => {:success => 'results'}

Is there any way to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Javascript to return false before executing controller action